# C# WPF Application Printing issue (PageOrientation property not existing)

Tags: c#, wpf, system.printing

Has anyone ran into problem where you just can't use the `PageOrientation` property in your C# WPF project? I have tried everything, put it still says:

> "The name 'PageOrientation' does not exist in the current context".

I have all usings included, just can't figure it out.

Here's my printing method:

```
private void btnPrindi_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PrintDialog prtDlg = new PrintDialog();
    if (prtDlg.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        **prtDlg.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;**

        Size pageSize = new Size(prtDlg.PrintableAreaWidth - 30, prtDlg.PrintableAreaHeight - 30);
        gridKaart.Measure(pageSize);
        gridKaart.Arrange(new Rect(15,15,pageSize.Width,pageSize.Height));
        prtDlg.PrintVisual(gridKaart,"Patsiendikaart");

    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error actually refers to the enumeration ([`PageOrientation.Landscape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.pageorientation.aspx)) on the right hand side of your assignment.

If the property did not exist you would receive (try compiling `"".Y` and you'll see what I mean):

> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Y' and no extension method 'Y' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Compare this to `Aoeui.Dhtns`:

> The name 'Aoeui' does not exist in the current context

You are likely missing a namespace reference required, like `System.Printing`:

```
// ...
using System.Printing;
// ...
```

The other possibility is you have not referenced `ReachFramework`.

If you have, your code compiles as-is:

[image: Seems to work]

Comment: I have system.printing reference and using added.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I added ReachFramwork referecne and after that it works. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for saving my time with the `ReachFramework` suggestion ^^